# INSERT query not working even though the syntax is correct

Tags: php, mysql, sql

My insert query isnt adding anything to the database, i checked my syntax and it is correct

```
$id = $_SESSION['id'];//the current book id
$name = $_SESSION['username'] ;
$rating = $_POST['rate'];
$review = $_POST['review'];
echo "<br>";
echo "$name"." -$rating"." -$review";

$insert = mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO rating (bid,rating,review) 
VALUES ($id,$rating,$review)");
```

I even input the insert query in through phpmyadmin with values but still it does not insert anything into the table, explain this please and be simple, i am a beginner.I am using WAMPserver for this

Comment: You'll need to put your values in quotes if they're strings

Comment: This is very unsafe. You need to sanitise those strings. `mysqli_real_escape_string()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try putting quotes around the values:

```
INSERT INTO rating (bid,rating,review) 
    VALUES ('$id', '$rating',' $review')
```

Answer (score 1):

You must use quote for the string insertion,

```
$id = $_SESSION['id'];//the current book id
$name = $_SESSION['username'] ;
$rating = $_POST['rate'];
$review = $_POST['review'];
echo "<br>";
echo "$name"." -$rating"." -$review";

$insert = mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO rating (bid,rating,review) 
VALUES ('$id','$rating','$review')");
```

if this does not works, than echo your query,

```
echo "INSERT INTO rating (bid,rating,review) 
VALUES ('$id','$rating','$review')";
```

and run in your phpmyadmin

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not correct. You are vulnerable to [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com), and haven't even bothered to check if the SQL is **TRULY** correct.

```
$insert = mysqli_query($con,"INSERT [snip] VALUES ($id,$rating,$review)");
                                                               ^------^--
```

Given that is probably `this product sucks`, your query is actually:

```
INSERT INTO ... VALUES(foo, bar, this product sucks)
```

which is an outright SQL syntax error.

Never **EVER** assume that your query will succeed. Assuming everything will fail, check for that failure, and treat success as a pleasant surprise:

```
$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql) or die(mysqli_error($con));
                                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

is the absolute bare minimum you should have, especially while developing/debugging